# Octobercms display count in columns.yaml

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

How to display the count relationship in column.yaml? Please check my code.

User.php Model

```
public $hasMany = [
    'views' => ['Acme\Analytics\Models\View'],
    'views_count' => ['Acme\Analytics\Models\View', 'count' => true]
];
```

columns.yaml

```
# ===================================
#  List Column Definitions
# ===================================

columns:
    views_count:
        label: Views
```

Display or return value

```
[{"user_id":1,"count":3}]
```

The return value is correct but i only need the count value to display in the column fields. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Correct answer is `useRelationCount`:

```
columns:
  views_count:
    label: Views
    relation: views_count
    useRelationCount: true
```

Other two answers here won't work. `select` will crash app with "field not found" error, valueFrom will push empty string, comma separated for every record.

Comment: This is an amazing solution!

Comment: How about for fields.yaml also?

Comment: What do you mean by fields.yaml? Something like "count of related items" isn't really form-editable and would be hard to make a field-type like that ;) but if you just want to display that count in a form view, you probably should use `type: partial` and `<?= $record->relation->count() ?>` in your partial.

For more advanced related records management October provides a lot of tools, check https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
# ===================================
#  List Column Definitions
# ===================================

columns:
    views_count:
        label: Views
        select: count
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very old question but I am facing the same issue.

Here is the solution

```
# ===================================
#  List Column Definitions
# ===================================

columns:
    views_count:
        label: Views
        relation: views_count
        valueFrom: count
```

You can read more at https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-relation